Como encontrar el error en php
Partiendo de la base que llevo mil años sin programar...
Tengo un control de accesos sencillo hecho en php y MySql. No lo tengo al exterior, lo ejecuto desde un XAMP y la gente accede por ip a la página que tiene un login. Hay sobre 50 usuarios y no entran todos al mismo tiempo.
En local me funciona como un tiro, pero cuando se conectan desde los móviles le cuesta un mundo cargar y ejecutar las cosas.
He revisado los logs de MySQL y parece que no tengo ahí el problema.
¿Como podría depurar esto?

Revisa los logs en el servidor. No puedes llevar mil años sin programar, no se programaba hace mil años.

@A.Cedano es un decir jajaja. Al OP, pues al menos sabes donde y cuando ocurre el problema, deberías partir por ahí luego de los logs, y comenzar con verificar el rendimiento desde chrome por ejemplo. Usa algunas páginas de validacion como https://pagespeed.web.dev/, las cuales identifican los problemas generales con los sitios.

Si hay que esperar unos años para cargar, probablemente es un timeout.  Por alguna razón, el servidor web no puede alcanzar el base de datos.

Otra posible causa de errores de ese tipo es que existan versiones diferentes de PHP o de MySQL en tu entorno local y en el servidor y eso genere algún tipo de incompatibilidad. Aunque si llevas más de mil años sin programar imagino que eres inmortal y no debías preocuparte por esas cosas que nos mantienen sin dormir a nosotros los mortales.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

¿Probaste usar xdebug?
